# JQuery on() does not fire on appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My event handler on a child element that is appended to parent is not invoked. Event handler on parent is invoked.

```
componentDidMount() {

  $(document).ready(()=> {

    $(".parent").on("click", ".child", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').doStuff();
    });

    $(".parent").click(function(e) {
      console.log("this is working");
      $(".parent").append('<div><a href="#" className="child">Do Stuff</a></div>'); 
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I assume the random `/` at the end of that `append` line is a typo?

Comment: Why in the world are you using jQuery in combination with React..? Pick one... also `$(#parent)` is invalid syntax...

Comment: Also you're missing quotes around your selector.

Comment: we are replacing React with JQuery but its WIP. Fixed typos.

Comment: You can't repeat ID in a page. Change child to a class

Comment: @charlietfl we are using class not id, I updated that in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that i was using `className` which is React specific way to refer to HTML element's `class` attribute. When I made this update, it worked.

```
$(".parent").append('<div><a href="#" class="child">Do Stuff</a></div>');
```